# Vue.js: set an evaluated / v-bound property in a script

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, web-frontend

I'm instantiating a vue.js component in JavaScript, and I can't figure out how to give it an evaluated property which in a template would be prepended with v-bind.
Suppose `foo = "a"` and `bar = "b"`.
Here is an example of how I would achieve this in a template:

```
<div :class="foo + ' ' + bar"></div>
```

Resulting div:

```
<div class="a b"></div>
```

However, when creating this element using JavaScript, setting the class property to "foo + bar" results in this exact string being set as the class.

```
new div("name", { class: "foo + bar" })
```

Resulting div:

```
<div class="foo + bar"></div>
```

Please note that this is a contrived example - I am not trying to concatenate strings, but instead trying to pass an evaluated property to a custom vue.js component in JavaScript.

How can I pass an evaluated property to a vue.js component created using JavaScript?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: not sure if i understand what you are trying to do here, but have you tried `<div :class="[foo, bar]"></div>` edit: ah you want to concat the string.. maybe something like; `<div :class="`${foo}${bar}`"></div>` (argh the backticks are getting screwed up in comments)

Comment: @keja I have clarified my original question based on your comment.

Comment: you could do something like; `new div("name", { class: foo + " " + bar })` like you did at the first example

Comment: @keja thanks - that would be correct at first, but the result would not be reactive; any future change to foo or bar would not update the value of the property. This the main point of the v-bind syntax.

Comment: ah i see so you want `<div class="foo + bar"></div>` to be evaluated by vue..